# postgresql manual plpgsql function declaration section not understand

Tags: plpgsql

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS

```
CREATE FUNCTION concat_selected_fields(in_t sometablename) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN in_t.f1 || in_t.f3 || in_t.f5 || in_t.f7;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

is `in_t` alias `sometable` alias name? I try to replicate it by following:

```
create function conca_selected_col_emp( in_t public.emp) returns text as $$
    begin
    return in_t.name || in_t.department;
    end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Obviously, this will not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should to work:

```
create table foo(a varchar, b varchar);

insert into foo values('hello', 'world');

create or replace function fx(arg foo)
returns varchar as $$
begin
   return arg.a || ', ' || arg.b;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

postgres=# select fx(foo) from foo;
┌──────────────┐
│      fx      │
╞══════════════╡
│ hello, world │
└──────────────┘
(1 row)
```

or alternative syntax:

```
postgres=# select foo.fx from foo;
┌──────────────┐
│      fx      │
╞══════════════╡
│ hello, world │
└──────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: maybe text and varchar directly `||` cast is not OK.

Comment: @Mark - There is implicit cast between varchar and text, so `||`  for values of these types should to work. varchar is +/- text type in Postgres.

Comment: Now I know the issue. ` select * from conca_selected_col_emp(emp);`  wrong way to call the function.